# Using the derivative on $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k = (1+x)^n$

Tags: derivatives, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How can the derivative be used with this:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k = (1+x)^n$$

to generate a second identity?

In a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3332901/48606), one of the answers involved taking the derivative of the binomial theorem to get to a second identity.

It is not clear to me how one is able to get from:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k = (1+x)^n$$

to some intermediate form which when $x = -1, n=5$ gives:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{5}k^4{5\choose k}(-1)^k = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the equality for $n=5$ and differentiate it $4$ times giving
$$\sum_{k=0}^5\binom5kx^k=(1+x)^5$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k\binom5kx^{k-1}=5(1+x)^4$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k(k-1)\binom5kx^{k-2}=20(1+x)^3$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k(k-1)(k-2)\binom5kx^{k-3}=60(1+x)^2$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\binom5kx^{k-4}=120(1+x)$$
Then multiply each identity by $x$ until we have $x^k$ in the summation thus giving
$$\sum_{k=0}^5\binom5kx^k=(1+x)^5$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k\binom5kx^k=5x(1+x)^4$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k(k-1)\binom5kx^k=20x^2(1+x)^3$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k(k-1)(k-2)\binom5kx^k=60x^3(1+x)^2$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)\binom5kx^k=120x^4(1+x)$$
Then note that
$$k^4=k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)+6k(k-1)(k-2)+7k(k-1)+k$$
hence we can combine the identities to give
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k^4\binom5kx^k=120x^4(1+x)+6\times60x^3(1+x)^2+7\times20x^2(1+x)^3+5x(1+x)^4$$
Then using $x=-1$ gives the identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^5k^4\binom5k(-1)^k=0$$

Note that it is always possible to write
$$k^n=a_0k(k-1)\cdots(k-n+1)+a_1k(k-1)\cdots(k-n+2)+\dots+a_{n-1}k$$
for some constants $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you took the derivative of both sides and then multiplied both sides by $x$ you would get

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k{n \choose k}x^{k-1} = n(1+x)^{n-1}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k{n \choose k}x^{k} = nx(1+x)^{n-1}$$

Then you would repeat that three more times so that you would get the $k^4$ factor on the LHS.  I'm not going to do the Product Rule on a Saturday for you, but whatever it is on the RHS it would equal $0$ when $x=-1$ if $n$ was sufficiently large (i.e. $n>4$) because there would be a (1+x) factor in every term.